# How to get the exact size of PopupMenuButton (or any widget)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get the `PopupMenuButton`'s size because it has a property `offset` which controls where the dropdown menu is rendered on the screen, and I want this one to be rendered such that the top left of the drop down menu is aligned with the bottom left of the `PopupMenuButton` (see image below).

My approach now is this:

```
extension TextExtension on Text {
  /// Calculates the size of the text inside this text widget.
  /// note: this method supposes ltr direction of text, which is not always true, but it doesn't affect the size that much, so
  /// keep in mind that the size returned may be approximate in some cases.
  /// The text inside this widget must be non-null before calling this method.
  Size getSize({TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    TextPainter tp = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(text: data),
        textDirection: textDirection ?? TextDirection.ltr)
      ..layout();
    return tp.size;
  }
}
```

And then when I define the `PopupMenuButton`, I do this:

```
Widget _dropDownMenu({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String title,
    required List<PopupMenuItem> items,
  }) {
    final text = Text(
      title,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
    );
    final textSize = text.size;
    return PopupMenuButton(
        child: text,
        itemBuilder: (context) => items,
        offset: Offset(0, textSize.height),
      );
  }
```

It works, but I don't like it. I think there must be a better way to do this.

This is how it looks like right now:

[image]

I tried `LayoutBuilder`, but it is returning infinite width constraints.

Is there a more clean way of doing this?

Comment: so the call stack to show the menu goes like this `showButtonMenu` -> `showMenu`  (which gets a `RelativeRect` from the previous method calculated using the given `Offset` by me -> `navigator.push(_PopupMenuRoute(...)`  -> `buildPage` -> `_PopupMenuRouteLayout`  (which gets the calculated `position` which is what I want -> `getPositionForChild` which has nuclear maths that I can't understand 100% as you can't imagine the 100 2D-coordinate systems in the heads of flutter devs when they wrote this code.

The question now is how can I benefit from all this? @pskink

Comment: *"The question now is how can I benefit from all this?"* - if you dont like the default position of popup menu just copy the whole `popup_menu.dart` and change the way [position](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c860cba910/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart#L1118) variable is calculated

Comment: @pskink that worked, I added this line to the widget's copied code: `x-=3.0;
    y += position.toRect(Offset.zero & size).height+3.0;`. But I never thought someday I will modify flutter's own code in this way (copy paste whole widget code and modify it) to get an intended behaviour. But idk is this considered the cleanest way to do this? If yes then please post it as an answer to accept it. Thanks for help :)

Comment: i would replace `button.localToGlobal(widget.offset, ancestor: overlay),`
with `button.localToGlobal(widget.offset + Offset(0, button.size.height), ancestor: overlay),` - imho `PopupMenuButton` API should be better: instead of static `offset` they should provide something like `offsetBuilder` that would pass `button.size` or something similar so you could build the offset based on that size

Comment: @pskink yeah I placed my code just before the code of `getPositionForChild ` where they recalculate `x` and `y` to make sure they don't go off screen. Although this solution works as I mentioned, but again I say idk if this is a good way of achieving intended behaviour, neither do I think the method in the question above which I used early is, they both look like dirty hacks

Comment: yeah when you put it like this it looks better, like a custom widget coming from a custom package, post it as an answer as it is better than the solution proposed in the question @pskink

Comment: feel free to post a self answer then... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no other way except the approach I mentioned in the question, or to modify the source code of the `PopupMenuButton` to make it accept an `OffsetBuilder` as pskink mentioned. This can be done like this (and there is full working example below):

- go to the `PopupMenuButton` source code and copy it all into a new file `custom_popup_menu.dart` (in this new file just remove all the imports and import them again as suggested by the IDE to fix them)
- add this to anywhere top level in the file: `Offset _defaultOffsetBuilder(Size size)  => Offset.zero;`
- inside the `PopupMenuButton` class replace `final Offset offset` with

```
  /// The button size will be passed to this function to get the offset applied
  /// to the Popup Menu when it is open. The top left of the [PopupMenuButton] is considered
  /// as the origin of the coordinate system of this offset.
  ///
  /// When not set, the Popup Menu Button will be positioned directly next to
  /// the button that was used to create it.
  final Offset Function(Size) offsetBuilder;
```

- inside the constructor of this class replace `this.offset` with `this.offsetBuilder = _defaultOffsetBuilder,`
- in the `showButtonMenu` method of `PopupMenuButtonState` class, replace

```
      Rect.fromPoints(
        button.localToGlobal(widget.offset, ancestor: overlay),
        button.localToGlobal(
            button.size.bottomRight(Offset.zero) + widget.offset,
            ancestor: overlay),
      ),
      Offset.zero & overlay.size,
    );
```

with

```
    final offset = widget.offsetBuilder(button.size);
    final RelativeRect position = RelativeRect.fromRect(
      Rect.fromPoints(
        button.localToGlobal(offset, ancestor: overlay),
        button.localToGlobal(
            button.size.bottomRight(Offset.zero) + offset,
            ancestor: overlay),
      ),
      Offset.zero & overlay.size,
    );
```

- #### Full Working Example:

```
... (imports)
import 'custom_popup_menu.dart' as pm;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomePage2(),
      );
}

class HomePage2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Align(
          alignment: const Alignment(0, -0.8),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 2.0)),
            child: pm.PopupMenuButton<String>(
              child: const Text(
                'Press Me',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 50),
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
                _buildPopupMenuItem(),
                _buildPopupMenuItem(),
                _buildPopupMenuItem(),
              ],
              color: Colors.red,
              offsetBuilder: (buttonSize) => Offset(0, buttonSize.height),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  pm.PopupMenuItem<String> _buildPopupMenuItem() {
    return pm.PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text(
        'Press Me ${Random().nextInt(100)}',
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 50),
      ),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

[image]